# Can't fill 2d-array by brackets in Kotlin despite getter and setter

Tags: arrays, kotlin, multidimensional-array, operator-keyword, getter-setter

It should become a little consolewalker program but I can't fill the 2d-array I created in class `Field` in class `Player` by brackets because there "are to many arguments" for set function despite there is one that should fit. Also I have learned that it isn't even necessary in Kotlin.
So I am a little bit confused and get no further.

```
fun main() {
val gameField = Field()

gameField.buildField()

val player = Player(gameField.field)

gameField.printField()

var input: String? = " "

while (input != "x") {

    println("w: ↑ a: ← s: ↓ d: →")
    input = readLine()
    when (input) {
        "w" -> player.counter = 0
        "a" -> player.counter = 1
        "s" -> player.counter = 2
        "d" -> player.counter = 3
        "x" -> return println("Spiel wird beendet")
        " " -> player.move()
        else -> println("Ungültige Eingabe")
    }
    player.setPlayer()
    gameField.printField()
}
```

}

```
class Field() {
private var field = Array(10) {Array(10){" "}}

operator fun set(row: Int, col: Int, value: String) {
    field[row][col] = value
}
operator fun get(row: Int, col: Int) = field[row][col]

fun buildField() {
    for (i in field.indices) {
        field[i][0] = "# "
        field[i][field.size - 1] = "# "
        for (j in 1 until field.size - 1) {
            field[i][j] = "  "
            field[0][j] = "# "
            field[field.size - 1][j] = "# "
        }
    }
}

fun printField() {
    for (i in field.indices) {
        for (j in field[i].indices) {
            print(field[i][j])
        }
        println()
    }
}
```

}

```
class Player(private var gameField: Array<Array<String>>) {
private val playerSign = arrayOf<String>("↑ ", "← ", "↓ ", "→ ")
var currentRow = 4
var currentColumn = 4
var counter = 0

init {
    setPlayer()
}

fun setPlayer() {
    gameField[currentRow, currentColumn] = playerSign[counter]
}

fun reset() {
    gameField[currentRow, currentColumn] = "  "
}

fun move() {
    reset()
    when(counter) {
        0 -> if (currentRow > 1) currentRow--
        1 -> if (currentColumn > 1) currentColumn--
        2 -> if (currentRow < gameField.size-2) currentRow++
        3 -> if (currentColumn < gameField.size-2) currentColumn++
    }
    setPlayer()
}
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with your code is that in class `Player` `field` is of type `Field`, its not an `array`, that is why compiler is giving you the error. if you want to access the field array of `Field` class then you should do

```
field.field[3][3] = playerSign[counter]
```

Comment: I'm such an idiot and wouldn't have come up with that idea. You definitely saved my a**, thanks!

Comment: While this works, I think that overloading the `get` and `set` operator is the cleaner solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend you `Field` class with an overloaded [`get`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/get.html) and [`set`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/set.html) operator (see [Operator Overloading | Indexed Access Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#indexed-access-operator) in the language documentation).

```
class Field() {
  // all your existing code

  operator fun set(row : Int, col : Int,  value : String) {
    field[row][col] = value
  }

  operator fun get(row : Int, col : Int) = field[row][col]
}
```

As the documentation states:

> Square brackets are translated to calls to `get` and `set` with appropriate numbers of arguments.

Thus, you now can write

```
field[currentRow, currentColumn] = playerSign[counter]
```

in your `Player` class which is more clean than exposing / accessing the array itself (which could and should now be made private).

Comment: I already noticed Kotlin is not that optimized for multidimesional arrays (especially of Strings). But regardles your advice seems coherent and usefull for future. Still I can't really implement it like that. Compiler asks for a "extension function 'String.set' when doing what you told me and additionally change class header to 'class Player(private var gameField: Array<String>)'. So, I found an other solution but am wondering why yours doesn't work for me. I also tried calling field.set(currentRow, currentColumn, playerSign[counter]) in setPlayer() but in vain. Hope you can still follow me...

Comment: I've updated the question and code with the baseline so you have a better understanding of what I mean.

Comment: @Elliot In your original question you used a `CharArray`, now you use a `String` array as row in your field. Please do not modify your code after you initially posted your question. You have to adjust the `get` and `set` operator to return / accept a `String`, not a `Char`